# how to query mongodb using findOne and exclude some nested fields in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to MongoDB, though I've used MySQL.

My user collection has user data with below shape -

I am creating `api in nodejs` that fetches given user's entire data but should **exclude** the `transactions` field from every data type.
my get data api: `localhost:5000/api/users/id/:id/data`

Please help me write the query. I've already created api to fetch all users, create user, update user but I'm stuck with this one only. I also tried using aggregate but it returns entire data including transactions. My attempt -

```
getUserData = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    try {
      const userData = await UserModel.findById(id).aggregate([
        { $project: { "data.v.transactions": 0 } }
      ]);
      if (!userData ) res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: `No data found` });
      res.status(200).send(userData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(400).send({ status: false, error });
    }
  }
```

I'm using `mongoose` package in my nodejs app.

One User Object in Users Collection --

```
{
  "_id": "615d6a2afabf089b94a116e6",
  "email": "john@doe.com",
  "data": {
    "TYPE_1": [
      {
        "type": "type_1",
        "transactions": {
          "endDate": "2020-09-17T14:25:33.440Z",
          "startDate": "2019-04-11T11:39:57.153Z",
          "transaction": [
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
        "profile": {
          "full_name": "John Doe"
        },
        "summary": {
          "note": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "type_1",
        "transactions": {
          "endDate": "2020-09-17T14:25:33.440Z",
          "startDate": "2019-04-11T11:39:57.153Z",
          "transaction": [
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
        "profile": {
          "full_name": "John Doe"
        },
        "summary": {
          "note": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "type_1",
        "transactions": {
          "endDate": "2020-09-17T14:25:33.440Z",
          "startDate": "2019-04-11T11:39:57.153Z",
          "transaction": [
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
        "profile": {
          "full_name": "John Doe"
        },
        "summary": {
          "note": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
      }
    ],
    "TYPE_2": [
      {
        "type": "type_2",
        "transactions": {
          "endDate": "2020-09-17T14:25:33.440Z",
          "startDate": "2019-04-11T11:39:57.153Z",
          "transaction": [
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
        "profile": {
          "full_name": "John Doe"
        },
        "summary": {
          "note": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "type_2",
        "transactions": {
          "endDate": "2020-09-17T14:25:33.440Z",
          "startDate": "2019-04-11T11:39:57.153Z",
          "transaction": [
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
        "profile": {
          "full_name": "John Doe"
        },
        "summary": {
          "note": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "type_2",
        "transactions": {
          "endDate": "2020-09-17T14:25:33.440Z",
          "startDate": "2019-04-11T11:39:57.153Z",
          "transaction": [
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            },
            {
              "mode": "A",
              "type": "AB",
              "amount": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
        "profile": {
          "full_name": "John Doe"
        },
        "summary": {
          "note": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "createdAt": "2021-10-06T09:19:39.378Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-10-06T09:19:39.378Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: what is the result you are trying to get?

Comment: @TobiasS. entire user object from collection without transactions field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give this one a try:

```
const userData = await UserModel.find({}, { 
    "data.TYPE_1.transactions" : 0, 
    "data.TYPE_2.transactions" : 0  
})
```

Comment: but I need to exclude transactions from every Type and not only Type_1

Comment: are there only type_1 and type_2 ?

Comment: @TobiasS. Instead of ignoring the fields you **don't** want you should instead select the fields you **do** want. This ensures that if you add new fields then you won't unintentionally select them.

Comment: Tobias,  there can be many types, I just mocked it. 
@MikeEason Please provide a generic solution either by excluding unwanted fields or by only selecting the wanted fields.